# How to debug a crash on an iOS 5 device with Xcode 4.0.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, crash

I've just released my first app to the app store.

I've been developing the app with Xcode 4.0.2 with iOS 4.2.1 devices. Because my device is a 2nd gen iPod Touch I can't get iOS 5 on it so I can't use Xcode 4.1 with it which also means I can't build to iOS 5 devices with my version of Xcode.

My friend who has a 3GS running iOS 5 has just downloaded the app, and one specific section of  it crashes when tapped (aaaah!) - it works fine for me.

I've just looked at his crash logs and they just show `EXC_CRASH(SIGBART)` - with nothing that can really help me determine the cause of the error.

I considered building to his device to get the runtime crash log (which shows an actual code-level exception), but I realised I can't because I'm using Xcode 4.0.2.

I can't upgrade my Xcode version because then I won't be able to test on devices myself!

What can I do?

Comment: What should you do?  #1) Buy a new iPhone so you can test with the latest iOS versions.  #2) In the meantime, send your friend ADHOC or Debug versions of your app with symbols turned on and plenty of Console logging and when it crashes, have your friend send you the crash logs and device console output back at you.  Hopefully that will help you narrow in on where your crash is happening.  But really, ultimately what you need to do is get a new device to stress test your app(s) out with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current Xcode version is 4.2 which does support debugging on devices with iOS 4.2.1 as I use an old iPhone 3G with 4.2.1 for debugging.

In Xcode 4.2 there is also a new section in the preferences window that says "Downloads". From that tab you can download additional packages, one of them is support for debugging with even older iOS devices.

Answer (score 1):

You can install a second copy of Xcode in a separate developer folder and then test using the latest Xcode with iOS5 in the simulator. There's a blog about how to install multiple Xcode versions here:

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/9/7/installing-multiple-xcode-versions.html

If you can't reproduce in the simulator, I suggest borrowing his device (you'll still need to install the latest Xcode though).